# ASP.NET Chart displaying between dates

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, charts

I've created an asp.net Line Chart using the method

```
DataBindCrossTable(reader, "Name", "Data", Quantity", "");
```

The chart displays a function of quantity per time, retrieved from this query

```
SELECT Products.Name, Shipments.Date,  COUNT(Products.Name) as Quantity
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Shipments
ON Prodotto.IdProdotto = Shipments.IdProdotto
WHERE Spedizione.Date BETWEEN [date] AND [date] 
GROUP BY Products.Name, Shipments.Date
ORDER BY Products.Name, Shipments.Date
```

(the `[date]` is a string)

Now, if I try to create a chart from this table

```
+----------+-------------+----------+
|   Name   |    Date     | Quantity |
+----------+-------------+----------+
| computer | 2014-03-25  |     2    |
+----------+-------------+----------+
|  stuff   | 2014-04-01  |     1    |
+----------+-------------+----------+
```

using those dates the chart won't display the first product.

While debugging I've found out that only the second row is saved in the Series, and in the chart image the x-axis is showing dates from `2014-03-31` to `2014-04-02`.

What am I doing wrong?

Also I've tried in the query to change the first date to `2014-03-24` and that way it works, but I don't want to manipulate the `[date]` string each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error: the `DataBindCrossTable()` method was inside a `while(reader.read()` and it skipped the first point of the first series. In a large chart it was unnoticeable.